# Kivy: better way to do timed events (dice rolling animation)

Tags: python, kivy, dice

I am writing a yahtzee clone to teach myself Kivy (I'm still very new to Python and programming in general), and I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to best animate the dice rolling. This code works as intended, but I feel like I'm missing something conceptually. Is there a less involved or cleaner way to have a Clock event happen for a set period of time?

This is what I currently have:

The parent layout holds 5 dice as children widgets. The user clicks a button to roll them all using this method:

```
def roll_all_dice(self):
    for dice in self.children:
        Clock.schedule_interval(dice.roll, .1)
        Clock.schedule_once(dice.roll_animation_callback, .5)
```

which, if I understand this correctly, schedules a roll every .1s, then .5s later, calls the roll_animation_callback, which stops the events.

Here are the relevant Dice methods:

```
def roll(self, *args):
    '''changes the number of the die and updates the image'''
    if self.state != "down":
        self.number = randint(1,6)
        self.source = self.get_image()

def get_image(self):
    '''returns image path for each of the die's sides'''
    if self.state == "down":
        return "images/down_state/dice" + str(self.number) + ".png"
    else:
       return "images/up_state/dice" + str(self.number) + ".png"

def roll_animation_callback(self, *args):
    '''turns off the dice rolling animation event'''
    Clock.unschedule(self.roll)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine, using the Clock like this is normal.